# Is it correct to write two "you(s)" one after the other? (see example)

Tags: sentence-construction

For example:

> The presents that I'm going to give **you you**'ll have to share with
>   your brothers.

Does this sentence sound natural? If not, how could it be rearranged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is grammatically correct to place two *you*s consequently because they are in different cases: the first one is in the oblique case (indirect object), the second one is the subject of the sentence.

I would rearrange the sentence slightly to make it sound more naturally:

> The presents I'm going to give you, you'll have to share with your brothers.

Answer (score 1):

It is something someone might **say**, but unless you were quoting spoken words it would be very odd to **write** that sentence. And if you did write it, there would be a temptation to  put some punctuation between the two you(s), not least because when spoken there would certainly be a pause between them. A full-stop (period) would do. A colon, possibly.

It is certainly not right for formal use.